# How Can I Rewrite This Line Without The Use of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got a quiz app here, I'm wondering how I can rewrite this conditional without the $.

```
if ($('input[name="radioOption"]:checked').length < 1) {
    alert('Please Make a Selection');
}
```

Here is a fiddle to all the code:: https://jsfiddle.net/scrippyfingers/z84pc45t/

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, you want to check whether ANY radio button is selected?

Comment: Replace `$` with `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @FelixKling well almost.... it returns null when not found.

Comment: @epascarello: `querySelector` does, `querySelectorAll` always returns a list.

Comment: OP would get "Cannot read property 'length' of null" if there would be no elements checked.

Comment: ahhh, I need coffee....

Comment: What level of browser compatibility do you seek?

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!document.querySelector("input[name='radioOption']:checked")) {
```

That should work for you.